# Treat Android as USB for forensics

Tags: linux, usb-connection-mode

I have a Galaxy S3 Mini. I want to plug it into Linux and treat it like a hard drive or USB device so I can use `Recoverjpeg` to recover photos from it, and use `dc3dd` so I can take the image of the Android files. I tried to do it on Kali Linux but when I tried use the command:

```
fdisk -l
```

I can't find it. Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 2):

Newer Android phones don't act as USB mass storage devices, so you can't use PC-based recovery software on them. Those tools (and the mass storage profile itself) require that the phone gives the PC very low-level access to the storage, which simply isn't practical any more. [Here's a longer explanation of why not.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56094/12442)