# Why do I need to use "Android File Transfer" to transfer files from my mac?

Tags: file-transfer, macos

I'm curious as to why I need to download and use 'Android File Transfer' so that I can transfer files from my mac to my nexus 5. I assumed because they had a similar file structure that viewing files on one from the other wouldn't have been an issue.

Comment: There's a good answer to the same question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/56094/137844

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because Mac does not have all the required drivers. It's like you can't connect your iPhone to a Windows computer properly without iTunes.