# When an app is moved to an external microSD card, to where is it moved?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, file-system, storage, app2sd

In Android KitKat on many devices, it is simple to move an app to an external microSD card.  It's as simple as *Settings -> Apps -> [Select the app] -> Move to SD card*.

For apps whose manifest allows them to be moved (something *every* good app should allow except when there is a valid reason to not), this works like a charm.

Doing this frees up the device's internal storage, allowing room for more apps.

But to where are the apps actually moved?

I thought the apps would be moved to the `Android/data` and `Android/obb` folders on the external SD card.  But upon examining those folders with several root file managers, the moved apps are not visible in those locations.

What's the story?  To where are those apps being moved?

---

I am voting to self-close this question, as I see another very similar question here: [When app is moved to SD card, where is the app data stored on SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127485/location-of-apps-moved-to-sd-card)

I'm not going to delete it because Susan's answer is very useful and appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps installed on the SD-Card are stored in the ".android_secure" directory.

You cant see the APK files directly in that folder because the it is encrypted to prevent direct access to the APK file of paid apps.